# How to determine how much capacitance to add at the output of a DC-DC converter?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I am looking to use a DC-DC converter on a test board to downconvert ~24 V to 5 V. I found this part from Traco (among other similar options) that seems to do the trick https://www.tracopower.com/products/tmr1.pdf. In the datasheet, the output ripple is specified as 110 mV pk-pk max at a 20 MHz bandwidth. From my understanding, adding more capacitance at the output will reduce the output ripple. The datasheet specifies that you can have 1680 uF max at the output for the 5 V variant. However, it does not specify how much the ripple will decrease with more capacitance. Is there a way to determine how much output capacitance I need for certain output ripple for this part? I also do not know how output capacitance translates into bandwidth. What output capacitance did they use to obtain a 20 MHz bandwidth?

Additionally, what are the downsides to using a larger capacitance? It should be slower to start up, but once started, the output should be pretty solid, right? Since this is a test board that will always be powered on, I do not care very much about startup time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding, adding more capacitance at the output will reduce the output ripple.

Yes, but:

1. It's a rather bulky way of reducing ripple,
2. A capacitor is a good ripple filter only up to its self-resonant frequency (SRF), and the *physically* larger the capacitor, the higher the SRF. Above the SRF, the capacitor's effectiveness decreases.
3. It causes high start-up loads on the converter, and whatever is powering it, potentially decreasing the service life of the circuit and its power supply.

Instead, use a fast LDO regulator to post-regulate the switching output. That will let you use reasonably sized capacitors, e.g. 2x100uF on the LDO input and output, although make sure you follow the requirements from the LDO datasheet as well. Modern LDOs will be specified for good line rejection till say 1MHz, and are a good match for switching converters.

For additional high-frequency filtering, a common-mode filter between the switching converter and the LDO's input capacitor could be added. Most common mode filters will have some differential-mode inductance as well and will act as both a common-mode filter, and as a series (differential) choke. You can select for common mode chokes that have a particularly high differential inductance relatively to their common mode inductance.

> What output capacitance did they use to obtain a 20Mhz bandwidth?

They didn't "obtain" the bandwidth. That's they bandwidth they *chose* to do their measurement in. So, if you wanted to reproduce their result, you'd use an AC amplifier with a 1st or 2nd order low-pass cut-off at 20MHz, or a sensitive AC/RF voltmeter set for 20MHz bandwidth.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot Kuba for the explanation and suggestion to use an LDO. So that means that I will have to find a switching converter that outputs higher than 5V, due the dropout of the LDO. It looks like most switching converters have outputs at 5V or 12V, but not a lot in between. So the LDO will be burning a lot of energy if I choose a 12V output, but since this is a test board, I also don't care about power efficiency.

Comment: Got it, so they are basically using an oscilloscope with the bandwidth set to 20Mhz and then measuring the pk-pk. Why don't the datasheets specify what output capacitance they use for the test though? It seems like they can make their part seem better or worse by playing around with the output capacitance.

Comment: @JohnAllen Good datasheets specify a test circuit. Bad datasheets... the low price you pay for the part is compensated for by the time spent testing the part. It's a tradeoff. Works for high volume cost sensitive stuff. A **lot** of circuits these days are laid out according to app notes, and they see the first test only when the first few PCBs are assembled. And changes after that point are often only made if necessary, and part-level validation tests are wishful thinking. So marketing tricks play a lot into sales, even if they are not very ethical.